# Codeigniter : I am trying to submit form either if user chooses any image to upload or not choose. is it possible?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Right now, submit form works good  when i am choosing image to upload . But i am trying to submit same form even if not choosing any image...

### controller

```
function create(){
        $this->data['categories'] = $this->News_model->getNewsCategories();
        $this->data['status'] = $this->status;

        if($this->input->post()){

            $title =$this->input->post('title');
            $slug =$this->input->post('slug');
            $desc =$this->input->post('desc');
            $category_id =$this->input->post('category');
            $upload_path = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/news';
            $field_name ='image';
            $temp_file_name = $this->file[$field_name]['name'];
            $file_name = time().'_'.$this->randomString(10).'.'.$this->getFileExtension($temp_file_name);

            if(!$this->uploadImage($upload_path,$file_name,$field_name)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->file_error);
            }
        else{
                $this->createThumbnail($this->file_data['full_path'], $upload_path.'/thumb/'.$file_name,75,50);
                if(!$this->News_model->insertNews($title,$slug,$desc,$category_id,$file_name)){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Record couldn\'n inserted. Please try again.');
                }
                else{
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'News created.');
                    redirect('admin/news');
                }
            }


        }
        $this->load->view('admin/template/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/news/create',$this->data);
        $this->load->view('admin/template/footer');
    }
```

if some one have idea to submit form for both the case, then help me to short-out this problem. thanks.....

Comment: explain your problem more

Comment: just want submit my form  without choosing any image to upload

Comment: and what error you get ?

Comment: there is no error , but these two function can't perform at same time

Comment: when i am trying to submit  form without choosing any image  there comes  "You did not select a file to upload."  and its just a flash error.

Comment: ok, you need if condition where you check if file is set or not

Comment: i need some logic in controller , so that i can able submit form for both the cases, ........getting my point..????

Comment: two peoples ans your question have look both may be u find solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code just put one if condition on file name is not empty

```
    function create(){
                $this->data['categories'] =  $this->News_model->getNewsCategories();
                $this->data['status'] = $this->status;

                if($this->input->post()){

                    $title =$this->input->post('title');
                    $slug =$this->input->post('slug');
                    $desc =$this->input->post('desc');
                    $category_id =$this->input->post('category');
                    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];

                    if(!empty($file_name)){

                    $upload_path = FCPATH.'assets/uploads/news';
                    $field_name ='image';
                    $temp_file_name = $this->file[$field_name]['name'];
                    $file_name = time().'_'.$this->randomString(10).'.'.$this->getFileExtension($temp_file_name);

                    if(!$this->uploadImage($upload_path,$file_name,$field_name)){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->file_error);
                    }
                    else{
                        $this->createThumbnail($this->file_data['full_path'], $upload_path.'/thumb/'.$file_name,75,50);
                    }
                   } 
                  if(!$this->News_model->insertNews($title,$slug,$desc,$category_id,$file_name)){
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Record couldn\'n inserted. Please try again.');
                        }
                        else{
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'News created.');
                            redirect('admin/news');
                        }
                    }



                $this->load->view('admin/template/header');
                $this->load->view('admin/news/create',$this->data);
                $this->load->view('admin/template/footer');
            }
```

Comment: found error on    `if(!empty($file_name){ ` change to     `if(!empty($file_name)){`

Comment: please have a look on  " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37563680/codeigniter-on-view-edit-page-previously-selected-values-are-not-showing "

Answer (score 0):

You can check file have uploaded or not by this:

```
 if (isset($_FILES['upload_field_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload_field_name']['tmp_name'])) {

  //load upload class with the config, etc...
  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

 }
```